# top: counting the number of processes belonging to a user

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

Is there way of counting the number of processes being run by a user in the unix/linux/os x terminal?

For instance, `top -u taha` lists my processes. I want to be able to count these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ps` to output it and count the number using `wc`, as:

```
ps -u user | sed 1d | wc -l
```

You can also dump `top` output and grep it, something like:

```
top -u user -n1 | grep user | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

This will show all of the users with their counts (I believe this would be close enough for you. :)

```
ps -u "$(echo $(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u))" o user= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to *nix, so perhaps I did not fully understand the context of your question, but here is a possible solution:

```
jobs | wc -l
```

The output of the above command is a count of all the processes reported by the jobs command.  You can manipulate the parameters of the jobs command to change which processes get reported.

EDIT:  Just FYI, this would only work if interested in commands originating from a particular shell.  If you want more control in looking at system-wide processes you probably want to use `ps` as others have suggested.  However, if you use `wc` to do your counting, make sure you take into account any extraneous white space `jobs`, `ps` or `top` may have generated as that will affect the output of `wc`.